# Junit Tests: NullPointerException is raised for jpa repositories

Tags: java, jpa, junit

I've used a separated bean configuration file for my beans instead of using spring-boot annotation like("component", "Service" or, ...) in the application:

```
@SpringBootTest
@ContextConfiguration(loader = AnnotationConfigContextLoader.class)
class CheckActiveWorkerTest {


    @Autowired
    UserJpaRepository userJpaRepository;

    @Test
    void execute_AddUser_exception() {
        userJpaRepository.get(....);
         .....
    }
}
```

The UserJpaRepository is an interface and it has `@Repository`.
When I run this test, the `userJpaRepository` will be null and the spring boot test runner could not find its bean. Eventually, this test raises a `NullPointerException`!

How can I use the JpaRepositories during the tests?

Comment: @Sarjit sorry it was just a typing problem here, I use 'Autowired' in the code and I've tried 'InjectMock' too but the problem exists still.

Comment: This might be because the bean UserJpaRepository.class is not in the application context

Comment: Add `@ContextConfiguration(loader = AnnotationConfigContextLoader.class, classes = {UserJpaRepository.class})` at the class so as to add the UserJpaRepository bean to the context